# Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [Websphere Application Server v8.5 JRE]'

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm attempting to migrate our WAS7 server application for WAS 8.5 deployment, and transporting it from RAD 7.5 to RAD 9.1 to do so.

My first attempt was successful, and I've even been able to load the application in my local host - but now I'm trying to build it off of a new ClearCase Stream, and I'm running into this error:

"Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [Websphere Application Server v8.5 JRE]'"

There is also an error stating "The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved", which I assume will be resolved when the error above is resolved.

Is there any way for me to remove the 'unbound' status of our Websphere Application Server v8.5 JRE, or some other way around this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your **Installed JREs** preference page must not have an entry named,  "Websphere Application Server v8.5 JRE", which is what the project's contents say to use. Right-click on that node in the **Package Explorer** and configure it to point to what will actually be used to launch the app server.